# PACKET_TX_RING only sending out first packet, then not doing anything anymore

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef RAWSOCKET_H
#define RAWSOCKET_H

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>

#include "IPPacket.h"

#define CONF_RING_FRAMES        128

/// Initialize a packet socket ring buffer
//  @param ringtype is one of PACKET_RX_RING or PACKET_TX_RING
static inline char *
init_packetsock_ring(int fd, int ringtype)
{
  tpacket_req tp;
  char *ring;

  // tell kernel to export data through mmap()ped ring
  tp.tp_block_size = 1024 * 8;
  tp.tp_block_nr = 1024;
  tp.tp_frame_size = 1024 * 8;
  tp.tp_frame_nr = 1024;
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, ringtype, (void*) &tp, sizeof(tp));

  int val = TPACKET_V1;
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_VERSION, &val, sizeof(val));

  // open ring
  ring = (char*)mmap(0, tp.tp_block_size * tp.tp_block_nr,
               PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

  if (!ring)
    return NULL;

  return ring;
}

/// transmit a packet using packet ring
//  NOTE: for high rate processing try to batch system calls,
//        by writing multiple packets to the ring before calling send()
//
//  @param pkt is a packet from the network layer up (e.g., IP)
//  @return 0 on success, -1 on failure
static inline int
process_tx(int fd, char *ring, const char *pkt, int pktlen, sockaddr_ll *txring_daddr)
{
  static int ring_offset = 0;

  struct tpacket_hdr *header;
  struct pollfd pollset;
  char *off;
  int ret;

  // fetch a frame
  // like in the PACKET_RX_RING case, we define frames to be a page long,
  // including their header. This explains the use of getpagesize().
  header = (tpacket_hdr*)(void *) ring + (ring_offset * 1024);

  while (header->tp_status != TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE) {

    // if none available: wait on more data
    pollset.fd = fd;
    pollset.events = POLLOUT;
    pollset.revents = 0;
    ret = poll(&pollset, 1, 1000 /* don't hang */);
    if (ret < 0) {
      if (errno != EINTR) {
        perror("poll");
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }

    ring_offset++;
    if(ring_offset >= 1024 * 8) ring_offset = 0;
    header = (tpacket_hdr*)(void *) ring + (ring_offset * 1024);
  }

  // fill data
  off = (char*)(((char*) header) + (TPACKET_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)));
  memcpy(off, pkt, pktlen);

  // fill header
  header->tp_len = pktlen;
  header->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;

  // increase consumer ring pointer
  /*ring_offset++;
  if(ring_offset >= 1024 * 8) ring_offset = 0;*/

  // notify kernel
  if (sendto(fd, NULL, 0, 0, (sockaddr*)txring_daddr, sizeof(sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
    perror("sendto");
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

class RawSocket
{
    public:
        inline RawSocket() { }
        inline void initialize() {
            sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));

            ring = init_packetsock_ring(sockfd, PACKET_TX_RING);

            ifreq ifr;
            memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
            strncpy((char *) ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ);
            ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
            int index = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
            ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);

            sll = new sockaddr_ll();
            sll->sll_family = AF_PACKET;
            sll->sll_ifindex = index;
            sll->sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);
            sll->sll_halen = htons(6);

            memcpy(IPPacket::our_mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, ETH_ALEN);
            memcpy(sll->sll_addr, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, ETH_ALEN);

            /*struct packet_mreq mr;
            memset (&mr, 0, sizeof (mr));
            mr.mr_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
            mr.mr_type = PACKET_MR_PROMISC;
            setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_PACKET,PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mr, sizeof (mr));*/
            //setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &optval, sizeof(int));
        }

        inline ~RawSocket() {
            close(sockfd);
        }

        inline void send(const IPPacket* ip) const {
            process_tx(sockfd, ring, ip->packet_ptr, ip->tot_len, sll);
            printf("TX\n");
        }
    protected:
        char *ring;
        int sockfd;
        sockaddr_ll *sll;
};

#endif // RAWSOCKET_H
```

ip->packet_ptr being a pointer to a packet containing ethhdr and iphdr and so on.
The packets are being correcly sent via "normal" PF_PACKET sockets.
Now I tried using the TX Ring feature. However, only the first packet ever gets sent (and it gets sent 100% correctly).
Nothing else seems to happen on the network layer (tcpdump -vvv -e shows no network traffic at all occuring!)
However, the sendto() calls get processed correctly.

Comment: This is probably not the main error, but what happens to ring_offset, if poll times out with a 0 return value and _TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE_ is not yet present? I guess you have already looked at [http://wiki.ipxwarzone.com/index.php5?title=Linux_packet_mmap](http://wiki.ipxwarzone.com/index.php5?title=Linux_packet_mmap)

Comment: I seem to have fixed the stuff by making the offset 256 (ring_offset * 256) instead of 1024. I just do not understand why, since I always told it the packets/frames are sized 1024?!

Comment: @Doridian I am having the same problem but moving the off set isn't helping. Did you ever work out why this is happening?

Comment: I have fixed this in my code now; you must use `PACKET_ALIGN(TPACKET2_HDRLEN);` if using tpacket_req v2 or `TPACKET_HDRLEN` if using tpacket_req v1. This will align you to a 16 byte boundary. In my case, in the examples they were using (for v2) `TPACKET2_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)` which is 32 but it wasn't working. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt test this functionality myself, but I think you have an error in configuring the `struct tpacket_req` fields. the _nr fields are quite large. See this example code (linked to from the [wiki](http://wiki.ipxwarzone.com/index.php5?title=Linux_packet_mmap) ):

```
/* Setup the fd for mmap() ring buffer */
req.tp_block_size=4096;
req.tp_frame_size=1024;
req.tp_block_nr=64;
req.tp_frame_nr=4*64;
if ( (setsockopt(fd,
    SOL_PACKET,
    PACKET_RX_RING,
    (char *)&req,
    sizeof(req))) != 0 ) {
    perror("setsockopt()");
    close(fd);
    return 1;
};

/* mmap() the sucker */
map=mmap(NULL,
    req.tp_block_size * req.tp_block_nr,
    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Comment: Also you can notice there is no need to cast the value of mmap.

Comment: Kernel documentation also has a section for calculating block and frame size values: 

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.rst#packet_mmap-buffer-size-calculator

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is a bit late but the documentation for this is still poor and examples are few, so hopefully this will help someone):

As per my comments above, this is the working code for me now (with no error checking, just a crude proof of concept):

```
struct tpacket2_hdr *hdr;
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < tpacket_req.tp_frame_nr; i += 1) {

    hdr = (void*)(mmapped_buffer + (tpacket_req.tp_frame_size * i));

    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t*)(hdr + TPACKET_ALIGN(TPACKET2_HDRLEN));

    memcpy(data, tx_buffer, frame_size);

    hdr->tp_len = frame_size;

    hdr->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;

}
int32_t send_ret = sendto(sock_fd, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
```